# java 8 - how to use current item inside stream.groupingBy

Tags: java-8, java-stream, grouping

I have list of String as input, and function that receive String as parameter and returns list of objects. I want to wrap it in map, where key - current String from list, and list of objects as a value - result that function.

```
List<String> keys = List.of("one", "two", "three");
public List<Entity> someFunction(String param) throws IOException;

//how to put it into map? 
private Mapt<String, List<Entity>> getEntities()  {
    Map<String, List<Entity>> map = keys.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
             client.someFunction(?)));//how to pass current item to "someFunction"? and probably whap the exception
    return map;
}
```

Comment: I get compiler error: someFunction(java.lang.String) can not be applied to <lambda parameter>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collectors.groupingBy` doesn't seem like the appropriate collector to use, since you don't seem to be grouping, you are just mapping a value to each key of the input `List`.

Use `toMap`:

```
private Map<String, List<Entity>> getEntities()  {
    return 
        keys.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), 
                                      k -> client.someFunction(k)));
}
```

Comment: Do note: `someFunction(String param) throws IOException`. Because of which, the use of streams even while collecting using `toMap` would not be as functional as it might look like.

Comment: That is what I looked for. I'll wrap someFunction call to local method with catching IOException